# Revert failed feature in the develop branch? git-flow development

Tags: git, git-flow

Let say Developers have been working on `A`,`B`,`C` and `D` features.

`A`,`B`,`C` and `D` features branches has been merged into Develop branch but QA have not passed the test for `C` feature in the develop branch. Time is running out and need to be deployed, we are ok to merge everything from develop to master apart from `C` feature for deployment

What is git-flow procedure for a failed feature that it already merged in the develop? Should it be removed from the develop (git revert)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our case, things go to Production from Stage, and only QA-approved features go to Stage.
If that is not your case, you can always revert the merge commit associated to the feature merge with `git revert -m 1 <merge-commit-SHA>`
If the branch was already deleted, checkout to a new branch from develop to keep the commits.

Git-flow is not written in stone. You should adapt it to your workflow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does QA test a feature before go to Stage? Deploy a feature? We have PHP Developers that work on the feature branches.

Comment: Feature branches are checked out from stage, when done, they go to develop (via PR) once the feature passes QA, the feature goes to stage, so the branch only "dies" when merged to stage, then stage is the branch to be released.
It's not exactly gitflow, but it works for our workflow. This way we make sure that the released commits have passed QA.

Comment: In the general git flow, you should create a release branch from develop and find a way to get only the desired commits there, cherry-pick is an option but have in mind that cherry-picked commits are _new_ commits, so you should think of a plan to avoid conflicts.
The moral of the story would be to create a workflow where you can be sure to not deploy from a place where there's potentially buggy (untested) code.